# Conditions in aggregations within Pivot

Tags: sql-server, pivot, aggregate-functions

Table #Temp:

```
ID    Name        Hobbies
1     xxx          Reading
1     xxx          Sports
1     xxx          Dance
2     xyz          Dance
3     yyy          Swimming
3     yyy          Reading
```

Now, I want the result set to be:

```
ID   Name    Reading  Sports  Dance  Swimming  
1    xxx      T        T      T        F
2    xyz      F        F      T        F
3    yyy      T        F      F        T
```

I have written the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT * FROM #Temp
)SRC
PIVOT
(
    COUNT([ID]) 
    FOR [Hobbies] in ([Reading],[Sports],[Dance],[Swimming])
) piv;
```

I got the following result:

```
ID   Name    Reading  Sports  Dance  Swimming  
1    xxx      1        1      1        0
2    xyz      0        0      1        0
3    yyy      1        0      0        1
```

So, I want to use conditions in aggregations like if (count(id) = 1 then 'T' else 'F'). Is it possible in Pivots and how to accomplish it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT case when Reading >0 then 'T' else 'F' end Reading ,
       case when Sports >0 then 'T' else 'F' end Sports ,
       case when Dance >0 then 'T' else 'F' end Dance 

FROM
(
    SELECT * FROM #Temp
)SRC
PIVOT
(
    COUNT([ID]) 
    FOR [Hobbies] in ([Reading],[Sports],[Dance],[Swimming])
) piv;
```

Comment: It works as expected. Thanks! But I cannot display ID in my result set as I have used in for aggregation. Is it possible to display ID too.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
SELECT ID,NAME,
       CASE WHEN Reading=1 THEN 'T' ELSE 'F' END AS Reading,
       CASE WHEN Sports=1 THEN 'T' ELSE 'F' END AS Sports,
       CASE WHEN Dance=1 THEN 'T' ELSE 'F' END AS Dance,
       CASE WHEN Swimming =1 THEN 'T' ELSE 'F' END AS Swimming ,
FROM(
        --your query here
)t
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
    Name,
    CASE Reading WHEN 1 THEN 'T' ELSE 'F' END AS Reading,
    CASE Sports WHEN 1 THEN 'T' ELSE 'F' END AS Sports,
    CASE Dance WHEN 1 THEN 'T' ELSE 'F' END AS Dance,
    CASE Swimming WHEN 1 THEN 'T' ELSE 'F' END AS Swimming
FROM
(
    SELECT * FROM @tblTest
)SRC
PIVOT
(
    COUNT([ID]) 
    FOR [Hobbies] in ([Reading],[Sports],[Dance],[Swimming])
) piv;
```